# How to access elements in a java List like Python negative slicing?

Tags: java, list, indexing

Hi I want to know how to access a List in Java like Python... concretely I know that in Python I can get easily the last element so:

```
foo=[1,2,3,4]
foo[-1]
Out: 4
```

And in general with indexes like -2 or -3 to get the numbers in a reverse fashion. I want to do it the same way with a list of Integers in Java without reversing the list because I have large Lists so it could take much time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo[-x]` (in Python) can be expressed as `foo[foo.length - x]` (in Java<sup>1</sup>), where `x` is an integer in `[0, foo.length)`.

While [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) can be used to slice an Array (and can be applied to the end as well), it cannot be used for a "backward" or "stepped" slice.

---

<sup>1</sup>The principle is the same for a List as well: `foo.get(foo.size() - x)`.